# How to obtain ContentResolver if not in context?

Tags: android

I 'm new about android.I need ContentResolver instance when modifying PhoneWindowManager file.but the PhoneWindowManager doesn't inherit the Context class.I don't know how to obtain
ContentResolver in this case .thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneWindowManager has a mContext object initialized so you can get the contentResolver using

```
mContext.getContentResolver()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a new class which extends PhoneWindowManager class. Add a new field of type Context in this new class. Make a constructor in which you provide a context:

```
MyClass( Context cont ){
   myContext = cont;    
}
```

Comment: but I use another answer 'method ,but also thanks your code +1

Answer (score 1):

If in some class in which there is no `context` then you can create a `constructor or a method` which takes the context and then use this context to get ContentResolver instance or to access any context related methods.